# Office 365 call site event Receiver but did not work event Receiver

Tags: office-365, event-receivers, sandbox-solution, office-365-developer, office-365-develop-tool

Office 365 Solutions upload then site event Receiver call & Feature activated, did not work Event Receiver..

Below Code And Error Image

**Code For Site EventReceiver**

```
public class Project_SiteEventReceiver : SPFeatureReceiver
{

    public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
    {
    try
    {
        using (SPSite site = (properties.Feature.Parent as SPSite))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = site.RootWeb)
            {              
    site.RootWeb.Features.Add(new Guid("a2992ae0-0a71-4443-b334-8a961c131d35"),true,SPFeatureDefinitionScope.Site);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
 }
```

[image]

Comment: What is the scope of feature for which you have written the Feature Receiver? If its a web scoped feature, properties.Feature.Parent should give you SPWeb instance.

Comment: Not to be that guy, but sandboxed solutions containing code is depricated so you really should not be developing new functionality using sandbox (specifically not for the cloud)